# Java: How to operate with big collections?

Tags: java, android

I have project, where that need to measure time of some operations with 3 types of collections. The problem is size of colections.
Max size of collections must be 10'000'000, and all operations must measure at the same time.

If I run operations in series, all work fine, but the milestone is parallel.
App crash with "OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError"

Also I set `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest

I had many of tries, here is some of them:

```
private void measureCollections(ArrayList<String> key, String size){
       Flowable.fromIterable(keys)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(key -> workPlease(key, size))
                .sequential()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(map -> timeValueSubject.onNext(map));
}


 private Map<String, Long> workPlease(String key, String collectionSize) {
        int size = Integer.parseInt(collectionSize);
        int data = size / 2;    

        List<Integer> list;

        if (key.contains(ARRAY)) {
            list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, data));
        } else if (key.contains(LINKED)) {
            list = new LinkedList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, data));
        } else {
            list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(size, data));
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (key.contains("addToBeginning"))
            list.add(0, data);
        else if (key.contains("addToMiddle"))
            list.add(size / 2, data);
        else if (key.contains("addToEnd"))
            list.add(data);
        else if (key.contains("searchByValue"))
            list.indexOf(data);
        else if (key.contains("removeInBeginning"))
            list.remove(0);
        else if (key.contains("removeInMiddle"))
            list.remove(size / 2);
        else
            list.remove(size - 1);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long value = endTime - startTime;

        Map<String, Long> map = saveAndMapData(key, value);

        return map;
  }
```

Comment: Easy answer, page your data and compute them chunk by chunk.

Comment: can I get any link to read about it?